# SmtpClient scalability issue (only two running requests)

Tags: c#, .net, networking, smtp, smtpclient

I'm trying to send bunch of emails using [`SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922.aspx) method from .NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2008 64-bit Enterprise with 32 CPUs.

During the debugging I've found, that only two requests are running simultaneously. That's weid considering I'm on server OS.

Here's a simple test case:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var t1 = SendEmail();
    var t2 = SendEmail();
    var t3 = SendEmail();
    var t4 = SendEmail();
    var t5 = SendEmail();
    var t6 = SendEmail();
    var t7 = SendEmail();
    var t8 = SendEmail();
    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}

static async Task SendEmail()
{
    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting [{0}]", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"));
        await smtp.SendMailAsync("...", "...", "Test", "Testing...");
        Console.WriteLine("Done [{0}]", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"));
    }
}
```

And the result. It starts quickly, but finishes in batches of two (see the times). Also checking opened connections in Process Explorer shows same behavior.

```
Starting [2013-03-07T14:27:17.4643296Z]
Starting [2013-03-07T14:27:17.4783382Z]
Starting [2013-03-07T14:27:17.4783382Z]
Starting [2013-03-07T14:27:17.4793387Z]
Starting [2013-03-07T14:27:17.4793387Z]
Starting [2013-03-07T14:27:17.4793387Z]
Starting [2013-03-07T14:27:17.4793387Z]
Starting [2013-03-07T14:27:17.4793387Z]
Done [2013-03-07T14:27:19.2070974Z]
Done [2013-03-07T14:27:19.2070974Z]
Done [2013-03-07T14:27:19.7541596Z]
Done [2013-03-07T14:27:19.7602234Z]
Done [2013-03-07T14:27:20.3880420Z]
Done [2013-03-07T14:27:20.3906050Z]
Done [2013-03-07T14:27:20.9254624Z]
Done [2013-03-07T14:27:20.9324577Z]
00:00:03.7476343
```

Is there a way to really spin up more requests?

Comment: Have you tried modifying System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit before creating the SmtpClient objects? Or smtp.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit in the code above?

Comment: Yes! That was the cause. If you add that as answer, I'll mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each ServicePoint object has a default limit of 2 concurrent connections. You can modify this for future ServicePoint instances by setting ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit. You can also modify ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit for existing instances - SmtpClient exposes a ServicePoint property that you can use to get hold of this.